# Trouble animating SVG paths with Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, animation, svg, framer-motion

I'm having problems trying to animate some SVG paths in a file I created in [Canva](https://www.canva.com/). It's my project's logo, so I can't really write the code by myself. I've optimized the file so it looks clean and small.

In React, I transformed the SVG into a React Component via [SVGR Playground](https://react-svgr.com/playground/). It seems to work perfectly apart from the path animations I wanted. It even animates the entire SVG (the opacity in motion.svg, for example), but not the path elements. The component:

```
const pathVariants = {
  hidden: {
    pathLength: 0,
  },
  visible: {
    pathLength: 1,
    transition: 1.5,
  },
};

export function ProjectLogo(props) {
  return (
    <motion.svg
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.8, delay: props.theme === 'dark' ? 1.2 : 0.4 }}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={500}
      height={500}
      viewBox="0 0 375 375"
      {...props}
    >
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="a">
          <motion.path
            variants={pathVariants}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="visible"
            d="M5.496 71h363.75v233H5.496Zm0 0"
          />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <g clipPath="url(#a)">
        <motion.path
          variants={pathVariants}
          initial="hidden"
          animate="visible"
          fill={props.theme === 'dark' ? '#f6f5fc' : '#000000'}
          d="m52.219 187.45 65.105 52.663-11.886 28.2-99.942-80.864L149.324 71.066v37.805Zm217.09-80.86-11.887 28.195 65.105 52.664-97.105 78.512v37.805l143.824-116.383Zm-48.797-35.524-98.211 232.7h31.93l98.214-232.7Zm0 0"
        />
      </g>
      <motion.path
        fill="#f0f"
        d="M150.043 180.994h-26.879v11.027h14.266c-2.23 7.133-8.43 12.32-16.5 12.32-10.16 0-17.368-8.285-17.368-18.445s7.208-18.449 17.368-18.449c3.601 0 6.847 1.008 9.441 2.813l8.07-8.07c-4.902-3.606-10.953-5.766-17.511-5.766-16.285 0-29.473 13.187-29.473 29.472 0 16.285 13.188 29.47 29.473 29.47 16.285 0 29.472-13.185 29.472-29.47 0-1.66-.144-3.316-.359-4.902Zm0 0"
      />
      <motion.path
        fill="#0ff"
        d="M154.496 183.166h-26.879v11.027h14.266c-2.23 7.133-8.43 12.32-16.5 12.32-10.16 0-17.368-8.285-17.368-18.445s7.208-18.45 17.368-18.45c3.601.001 6.847 1.009 9.441 2.813l8.07-8.07c-4.902-3.605-10.953-5.765-17.511-5.765-16.285 0-29.473 13.187-29.473 29.472 0 16.285 13.188 29.469 29.473 29.469 16.285 0 29.472-13.184 29.472-29.469 0-1.66-.144-3.316-.359-4.902Zm0 0"
      />
      <motion.path
        variants={pathVariants}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="visible"
        fill={props.theme === 'dark' ? '#f6f5fc' : '#000000'}
        d="M152.27 182.08h-26.88v11.027h14.266c-2.23 7.133-8.43 12.32-16.5 12.32-10.16 0-17.367-8.285-17.367-18.445s7.207-18.449 17.367-18.449c3.602 0 6.848 1.008 9.442 2.813l8.07-8.07c-4.902-3.606-10.953-5.766-17.512-5.766-16.285 0-29.472 13.187-29.472 29.472 0 16.285 13.187 29.469 29.472 29.469 16.285 0 29.473-13.184 29.473-29.469 0-1.66-.145-3.316-.36-4.902Zm0 0"
      />
    </motion.svg>
  );
}
```

The only two paths I really want to animate are the ones that use logic in "fill" property. I've tried both using variants and passing the objects directly into initial, animate and transition properties. Neither works. Is it possible that some other element is blocking the effect? Or do I need to use something other than pathLength? Thank you.